# Code inside SKAction run action not executing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

The code block inside a `SKAction.run` action never executes for some reason.

To clarify, it's the two lines inside of `startAction` that never run for some reason even though the other lines do run.

Putting breakpoints on those lines prove those lines never execute.

Any clue why?

```
    // Set first frame
    let firstFrame = frames[0]
    let animationNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrame)
    animationNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

    // Set start action
    let startAction = SKAction.run({
        gAudio.playSound(file: .TestSound) // Never runs
        self.animationLayer.addChild(animationNode) // Never runs
    })

    // Set rest of animation
    let timePerFrame = 0.5
    let animationAction = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: timePerFrame, resize: false, restore: true)
    let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let animationSequence = SKAction.sequence([startAction, animationAction, removeAction])

    // Run animation
    animationNode.run(animationSequence)
```

Comment: run is immediate, but the block will go onto a queue and is not guaranteed to fire at exact time run is called, so as soon as you fire it, the next sequence will fire, thus removing the node from parent before anything in the run can happen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks so much, why not post as an answer? this seems to explain the problem, no?

Comment: only if the animation is not running either

Comment: @Knight0fDragon only if the animation is not running? Could you post as an answer since, if you're sure of these details, it explains the problem?

Comment: animationAction <--- if this is not running either then it is the answer

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what do you mean exactly? Are you saying there is a way to fix this by rearranging the actions?

Comment: no, I am asking does the animate action run

Comment: if you never add the node to the scene then actions never fire

Comment: @Knight0fDragon correct :) That's why the code inside the run action not firing is so problematic!

Comment: no it is not a problem it is doing exactly what it is suppose to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131106/discussion-between-crashalot-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: You are yelling at your dvd player because it is not playing your dvd movie, but you forgot to put the dvd in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions will not fire for a node until it is placed on the scene,  you have a chicken and egg dilemma going on here.  You want to add the node (egg) to the scene (chicken) after the node (egg) exists in the world (chicken gives birth to the same egg).  You need to have somethings else place the node on the scene, then the node will be able to run the actions.

Place your start action on your scene, and not your node, and it should start running

Comment: Thanks again! Actually the part of your explanation that seemed most insightful was the bit about the timing actions and how to guarantee a sequence of actions involving the `run` action. Want to include that bit as well?

Comment: no because it doesn't pertain to your problem and will only confuse people

Comment: @Knight0fDragon could you please take a look at this post for me. I've been at it for quite a while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602058/how-to-interrupt-a-spritekit-sequence-of-actions-and-resume-as-if-there-was-no-i/42610735#42610735