# How to interrupt a SpriteKit sequence of actions and resume as if there was no interruption

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, skaction

I would like to interrupt the sequence below for 2 seconds and resume to where it would have been if it wasn't interrupted in the first place.

For example, from the code below, if I were interrupt the sequence for 2 seconds by making the sprite visible from 1.5 - 3.5 seconds into the sequence (meaning that 1 second the `hideInterval` action plus the `showSprite` action, and 0.5 seconds of the `showInterval` action would be missed) the interruption would end at 2.5 seconds remaining for the `showInterval` action. How can I get the sprite to run an action on the remaining 2.5 seconds and continue with the normal sequence at that point.

Please note that this example is for clarity, though I would prefer a more generic way to resume a sequence after interruption.

```
    let hideSprite = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 0.5)
    let showSprite = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 100, duration: 0.5)
    let hideInterval = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    let showInterval = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let spriteSequence = SKAction.sequence([hideSprite, hideInterval, showSprite, showInterval])
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatForever(spriteSequence))
```

**UPDATE**

I think the following diagram will make my question more understandable and explain further what I want to achieve with the interruption of the sequence.

[image]

Comment: A sequence of actions can be interrupted in two ways : 1) by pausing the action, 2) by removing the action. You are not doing any of that. Can you please specify *how* you make an interruption, because what you have described can't be considered as interruption of a running action.

Comment: @Whirlwind I have updated the question

Comment: @Whirlwind I am still trying to get this working

Comment: Your diagram is incomprehensible. Can you explain better in a simple word sequence what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I want to interrupt a sequence for a certain duration and resume the sequence (not at the action which it was interrupted on, but) at the action it would have reached if it wasn't interrupted for the duration.

Comment: Yikes, you are asking for something really complex, it sounds like you want to inject an action into another action, thus causing the other action to split into to separate actions [action 1][action 2] -> [action 1][action 2a][action 3][action 2b]  In this scenario, what I would do is create a copy of your sprite, pause and hide your original sprite, show the copy, perform the new action on the copy, and whatever the end result is, transfer it back to the original sprite, show and unpause the original, and destroy the copy

Comment: @ItsMeAgain Too generic, you should specify exactly what actions are involved in this sequence and describe exactly what do you want to do it, your question can't pretend a more generic way to resume a sequence. What happened if a `SKAction` of this sequence is a group of instructions (`SKAction.run`) that involved other nodes and/or lauch methods? At this point, are you really sure your sequence is paused? The answer is : you can't.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I have given a specific case in the question where there are 4 actions in the sequence that is interrupted for 2 seconds.

Comment: @ItsMeAgain You can't pause a sequence of actions for example by settings it's speed to 0, a sequence don't not responding as temporally respond a normal action because it's an action that runs a collection of actions sequentially. About your 4 actions you can pause the sprite or the node the execute (changing the `isPaused` property) the sequence whenever you want and you will can see a real pause/resume of the sequence: during these variations you can take informations about your sprite, decide when restart it, make other things..

Answer (score 1):

To interrupt the action sequence like yours, you can simply put in pause your sprite with:

```
sprite.isPaused = true
```

and to resume the action you can do:

```
sprite.isPaused = false
```

To make some specific action after a time you can simply made:

```
sprite.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.5),completion:{
   print("after 2.5 sec do..")
})
```

To answer about your "generic method to stop an action sequence" you can't pause a sequence of actions for example by settings it's `speed` to 0, a sequence don't not responding as temporally respond a normal action because it's an action that runs a collection of actions sequentially. An example or explaination about my words could be when you can have an action that report sub-actions / code that calls other scenes / calls to other methods so it's impossible to stop the sequence with the ordinary knowed methods.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. I just updated the question. I believe what I want to achieve is different from your answer.

Comment: You have many instruments to achieve this sequence: as I said in my answer you can run some code after tot secods, doing parallels run making SKAction.group or sequences. You can also freeeze your sprite with isPaused property. You should build your actions sequence following the Sprite-kit class methods

Comment: Actually, what I really want to do is tap the screen to interrupt a sequence, in that case I don't know the exact remaining time for a current sequence before interrupting it

Comment: Would you please explain further how I could achieve this with SKAction group. I have tried using the isPaused property but it starts the action all over again, it doesn't continue from where it would have been if it wasn't interrupted.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano what ItsMeAgain is trying to achieve is not that simple - pausing/interrupting a sequence for a certain during and keeping track of where the sprite in the sequence if it wasn't interrupted for that duration to continue the sequence from that place. This could be in the middle of an action